# In Vim, how to scroll past the beginning of the file?

Tags: vim, scrolling

In Vim you can scroll past the bottom/end of a file with the mouse wheel or with ctrl-E. It adds a ~ per line.

However when using ctrl-Y or the mouse wheel to scroll up, you can't scroll past the beginning of the file. Is this possible?

Comment: Why would you need to do this? I can't think of any reason why you would need to but if you explain what you are trying to accomplish that would need this, maybe there is an alternative solution.

Comment: @EBGreen I have a vertical 2560x1440 screen, I would just like to center small files on the screen.

Comment: I can see that being a valid desire. I would point out though that this desire is an indication that ergonomically your monitor setup is not optimal.

Comment: `:split` could help

Comment: @romainl I know there are many ways of fixing my problem. Nevertheless it would have been cool for Vim to have this feature. I don't know any editor that has this.

Comment: Take a look at Light Table: one of the author's aims is to disconnect the notions of "code" and "file" notably by displaying chunks of code in little boxes grouped by relationship instead of arbitrary location. It may be a little overkill, though.

Answer (score 4):

No it's not possible to go above the first line.